# Pyinstaller: WARNING: lib not found

Tags: python, pyqt, windows-10, pyinstaller

I'm trying create an executable from my code that uses PyQt5. I'm using Python 3.5.3 -64 bits, developing in Windows 10, used pip to install pyinstaller 3.2.1, and installed pywin32. Pyinstaller runs but outputs warnings that libraries aren't found.

I'm creating my application using the following:

```
pyinstaller Start_UI.py
```

Which outputs [these warnings](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zeHj7rFc_rWgtnoTVpd3YDxqgdbZh6YZxmdy5kwUXMQ/edit?usp=sharing).

```
pyinstaller Start_UI.spec
```

Which outputs [these warnings](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vl9JjPRvCmFJlddNddSpThgv0QpMU0Yu8DbijXngT8k/edit?usp=sharing)

When I open the executable that pyinstaller creates, the application closes immediately. I suspect the application is failing because of the warnings. How can I resolve the warnings so the executable works?

Thank you for the replies.

**Edit:**
I searched for DLL files on my computer and copied them into the dist folder which resolved the warnings output by:

```
pyinstaller Start_UI.py
```

As for:

```
pyinstaller Start_UI.spec
```

I located the mission api-mis-win-crt-* dll files in my installation of Windows SDK, and copied them into dist as well. This time, the warnings were not resolved as pyinstaller can't locate the dll files. Where do I need to put the api dll files for pyinstaller to locate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, the problem is because of Windows 10. While I didn't find a Windows 10 solution, I did solve my problem in Windows 7.

I tested pyinstaller on Windows 7 and was still getting warnings, but not the api-ms-win-crt-*.dll warnings.

I copied all the dll files in my Python35 directory into the pyinstaller generated dist folder. At this point, pyinstaller can turn a Hello World program into an executable without errors:

```
pyinstaller --onefile Hello_World.py
```

However, turning a PyQt5 program into an executable gives errors because pyinstaller can't locate the Qt5*.dll files. To fix this copy the PyQt5, Qt5*.dll files, under Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/bin and into dist. Then tell pyinstaller where the dll files are using --path:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --path dist Start_UI.py
```

This creates a working executable Start_UI.exe in dist.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error was due to **vcruntime140.dll** not being included in the dist folder. Check the executable after manually copying it to the `dist` folder

Comment: The folder hierarchy is workingDir/dist/Start_UI. I checked Start_UI and saw VCRUNTIME140.dll was already included in it. I copied VCRUNTIME140.dll into dist like you suggested, ran pyinstaller, but the warnings haven't gone away and the executable still fails.

Comment: have you tried including all DLL's to your **dist** folder?

Comment: I used window's search to find ~140 DLL files and then I copied them to dist. The command "pyinstaller Start_UI.py" has no warnings now, but "pyinstaller Start_UI.spec" is still full of errors (no api dlls). The executable still doesn't work.

Comment: does copying all those dlls to outside the dist folder where your spec files are work?

Comment: I haven't tried it. But I believe as long as you specify the path to the dll files, you should be able to have them there.

Comment: Yup that's the point. Except specifying the paths it can be also done by placing all those files there itself such that it can access them. Glad if I was of any help.