# Pyinstaller ImportError when using umap-learn and numba

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am developing a GUI which uses the new umap-learn library (https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap) but when I attempt to create the executable using pyinstaller I receive the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FM Working Directory\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zwebb2\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "FM Working Directory\_Frame.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zwebb2\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "FM Working Directory\_Preprocess_functions.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zwebb2\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "FM Working Directory\KNNDPP.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zwebb2\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zwebb2\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zwebb2\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zwebb2\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zwebb2\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 144, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zwebb2\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zwebb2\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zwebb2\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zwebb2\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[20040] Failed to execute script __init__
```

Does anyone else encounter this error? It seems to be a problem with pyimod03_importers.py.

Comment: `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` Have you tried googling this error? You're likely missing a file.

Comment: Yes, I've googled around but found fixes that didn't work. What kind of file do you suspect is missing?

Comment: A DLL file as is stated in the error... open the file and see what module it's trying to import. Make sure you have that module installed.

Comment: i was able to fix the DLL errors using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44660752/pyinstaller-warning-lib-not-found
I copied all the extra-dlls from Lib/site-packages/scipy/extra-dlls to the folder where I was running pyinstaller and it worked