# Convert Python Flask Webservice to Windows Service

Tags: python, flask

I am very new to Python. I have a flask API written and I am facing some issues with that. I want to run this API in a server and initially I planned to create a bat file and run the service in the task scheduler. However I ran into some file permissions issues. I have a code snippet which generates the log file in the directory and when I run the python code directly, it generates the log file but when ran in task scheduler it doesn't.

Hence I though I can go with a Windows Service which gives more flexibility. Below is my code for the windows service and my sample API python code as I wont able to provide my full code. What I am doing here is I query a table get few values, use a document template and populate the values in placeholders and finally, I save the document as a PDF in a folder. I have a Web UI from where I invoke a call to this API to generate the document based on values provided from UI.

--- API Python Code ---

```
    import ast
    import logging
    import os
    import traceback
    import pandas as pd
    import win32com.client
    import pythoncom
    from docx.shared import Mm
    from docxtpl import DocxTemplate, RichText, InlineImage
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    from datetime import datetime
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
    from waitress import serve
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    wdFormatPDF = 17
    logging.basicConfig(filename='Logfile.log', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
    # path setting
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    ET_doc = DocxTemplate(template_Path + "Generated.docx")
    
    def narrative_settings(structure_No, cla_engine):
        # ticket 4912 - Active column included
        ns_select_query = "SELECT * FROM Settings where structureNo = '{structure_number}' and Active = 1".format(structure_number=structure_No)
        settings_df = pd.read_sql_query(ns_select_query, cla_engine)
        image_path_var = settings_df['logoFile'].iloc[0]
        ns_report_location = settings_df['FolderPath'].iloc[0]
        eot_logo = InlineImage(ET_doc, image_descriptor=image_path_var, width=Mm(15), height=Mm(15))
        ds_logo = InlineImage(DS_doc, image_descriptor=image_path_var,
        width=Mm(15), height=Mm(15))
    return eot_logo, ds_logo, ns_report_location
        
        @app.route("/generation/", methods=['GET'])
        def base():
            report_date_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            eot_logo_var, ds_logo_var, report_location = narrative_settings(structure_no, cla_engine)
            
            context = {'structure_no': structure_no, 'Logo': eot_logo_var,
            'report_time': report_date_time}
            ET_doc.render(context)
            ET_doc.save(report_location + doc_file_name)
            pdf_file_name = f'Narrative_{subj_id}_{report_date}.pdf'
            word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application", pythoncom.CoInitialize())
            doc = word.Documents.Open(report_location + doc_file_name)
            doc.SaveAs(report_location + pdf_file_name, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
            doc.Close()
            word.Quit()
            os.remove(report_location + doc_file_name)
            report_status = "Generated"
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
     serve(app, host="", port=7105)
     app.run(debug=True)
```

---- Service.Py ----

```
import servicemanager
import sys
import win32serviceutil
import threading
import concurrent.futures
import time

from na_webservice import app

class workingthread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, quitEvent):
        self.quitEvent = quitEvent
        self.waitTime = 1
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        try:
            # Running start_flask() function on different thread, so that it doesn't blocks the code
            executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
            executor.submit(self.start_flask)
        except:
            pass

        # Following Lines are written so that, the program doesn't get quit
        # Will Run a Endless While Loop till Stop signal is not received from Windows Service API
        while not self.quitEvent.isSet():  # If stop signal is triggered, exit
            time.sleep(1)

    def start_flask(self):
        # This Function contains the actual logic, of windows service
        # This is case, we are running our flaskserver
        test = FlaskServer()
        test.start()

class FlaskService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "Service"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Narrative Service"
    _svc_description_ = "Web Service for executing python code"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = threading.Event()
        self.thread = workingthread(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.hWaitStop.set()

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        thread = Thread(target=app.run())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        while (1):
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 1000)
            if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                # Stop event
                break
        self.thread.start()
        self.hWaitStop.wait()
        self.thread.join()
        self.start(app);


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(FlaskService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(FlaskService)
```

I followed the steps provided in this post [Stackover flow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677165/python-flask-as-windows-service)  however I dont know how to call my flask API into the windows service code. I have just imported the flask API in my service.py but didnt understand how I can call it in this. Can someone guide me on how to do this.